# Url not coming on the address bar

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im using the below code of ajax

```
// JavaScript Document
function createTeam() {
    var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
    if(name==null || name==""){
        var div3 = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
        var text = "Enter Team";
        div3.style.display = "block";
        div3.style.color = "red";
        div3.style.fontSize = "65%";
        div3.innerHTML = text;
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST","/TeamServlet?name="+name+"&task=create",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= readResponse;
    }
    function readResponse(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
        {
            response = xmlhttp.responseText;
            $('#button').hide("slow");
            if(response == "false"){
                var div2 = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
                var text = "Unable to create team.";
                div2.style.display = "block";
                div2.style.color = "red";
                div2.style.fontSize = "65%";
                div2.innerHTML = text;
            }
            if(response == "true"){
                var div = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
                var text1 = "Team created.";
                div.style.display = "block";
                div.style.color = "red";
                div.style.fontSize = "65%";
                div.innerHTML = text1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But what happens is when I use this ajax the URL doesnt appear on the address bar of the browser.how can I achieve that? The only url that comes is that after I submit my login form, and that is this  http://localhost:8080/LoginServlet?task=login
but after this,even if I navigate to other jsps/servlets none of those url come.How can I fix this ajax code?

Comment: I think on xmlHttp Request it want come.

Comment: Ajax URLs won't get displayed in the browser addressbar.

Comment: is there any way by which we can make that happen?

Comment: You can trigger a hash-change, but if you change the full address the page will reload. Having said that, this might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: I am ready to go for jquery for that,if it is possible with jquery?If it is can anyone tell how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic purpose of AJAX: do Asynchronous request, on the "background". All request done with AJAX doesn't trigger the loading icon of the browser nor change the current URL.

If you want to do something like that, you should have a look to the `HTML5 History API`. Because it's a huge subject, I can't show you "one" answer but I give you some resource to get in:

- explanation & demo http://html5doctor.com/history-api/
- explanation & demo http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introducing-the-html5-history-api/
- explanation & demo http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html
- explanation & demo http://robertnyman.com/2011/08/03/html5-history-api-and-improving-end-user-experience/
- demo http://html5demos.com/history

The problem you'll find is that this API is not supported in all browsers, so you'll need to use a *polyfill* to make your code cross-browser compatible. Here is a list of cross-browser polyfill you can use:

- History.js https://github.com/browserstate/history.js
- PJAX (pushState + ajax = pjax) http://pjax.heroku.com/
- hashchange jQuery event http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/
- HistoryManager Mootools Plugin http://mootools.net/forge/p/historymanager/
- SWFAddress http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/ & jQuery Address http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/
- jQuery History Plugin https://balupton.com/projects/jquery-history
- jQuery Ajaxy http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-ajaxy
- Hasher https://github.com/millermedeiros/hasher/
- sHistory https://github.com/tatsh/sHistory

This list is maintained by the Modernizr team, the lasted version is available at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to display url of an ajax request in address bar? Ajax requests are to be performed if you want to make calls to the server without navigating away from current page. If you want to change url in address bar then you will have to redirect the user to the said url, you don't need Ajax for that.

Comment: I want to display URl because in my J2EE application,there is requirement that if I copy the URL from one tab and paste it to other then it should open the same page(rather same state should be shown.)

Comment: using the `HTML5 History API`, we both can do AJAX requests & changing the URL at the same time, check my answer to get more info on that subject